# Kubernetes - Readiness probe not working for deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, readinessprobe

Can someone please tell what is the issue with my yaml file for deployment. When I remove readiness probe, I can see my deplyoment in `kubectl get deployments` as available. But with readiness probe, it remains unavailable as below.

```
NAME           DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
neg-demo-app   1         1         1            0           2m33s
```

Below is my yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: neg-demo-app # Label for the Deployment
  name: neg-demo-app # Name of Deployment
spec: # Deployment's specification
  minReadySeconds: 60 # Number of seconds to wait after a Pod is created and its status is Ready
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: neg-demo-app
  template: # Pod template
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: neg-demo-app # Labels Pods from this Deployment
    spec: # Pod specification; each Pod created by this Deployment has this specification
      containers:
      - image: container_name  # Application to run in Deployment's Pods
        name: hostname # Container name
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60 # Number of seconds to wait for connections to terminate before shutting down Pods
```

Comment: pls provide more info. what's the pod event if you added readiness probe?

Comment: Does yor container returns 200 on `/healthz` endpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What i think you have added the

```
minReadySeconds: 60 # Number of seconds to wait after a Pod is created and its status is Ready
```

> minReadySeconds is an optional field that specifies the minimum
>   number of seconds for which a newly created Pod should be ready
>   without any of its containers crashing, for it to be considered
>   available. This defaults is 0 (the Pod will be considered available as
>   soon as it is ready).

```
So your newly created app pod have to be ready for minReadySeconds 60 seconds to be considered as available.


initialDelaySeconds: Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated.
```

> So initialDelaySeconds comes before minReadySeconds.

```
container in the pod has started at 5 seconds. Readiness probe will be initiated at 5+initialDelaySeconds seconds. Assume Pod become ready at 7 seconds(7 > 5+initialDelaySeconds). So this pod will be available after 7+minReadySeconds seconds.
```

Please try adding the `initialDelaySeconds` in rediness probe and liveness probe otherwise try with removing the `minReadySeconds`.

Comment: There is nothing to do with 200-300 both work if 301 is there at rediness probe end. if you can go inside pod and try `curl:localhost:8080/healthz` or check the description of pod using `kubectl describe` may possible there is some issue from application side.

Comment: Thanks. My application was not responding to that endpoint. But my ingress service is in UNHEALTHY state. I have opened another question for that if you can please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396949/kubernetes-ingress-service-shows-unhealthy-state