# Kubernetes - ingress service shows UNHEALTHY state

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am using this tutorial [ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing) on GCE. The tutorial works fine with docker image in it but with my docker image, I always get UNHEALTHY state of backend service. 
I added liveness and readiness TCP probes as my application does not respond to '/' with 200. 
The deployment yaml look like below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: neg-demo-app # Label for the Deployment
  name: neg-demo-app # Name of Deployment
spec: # Deployment's specification
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: neg-demo-app
  template: # Pod template
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: neg-demo-app # Labels Pods from this Deployment
    spec: # Pod specification; each Pod created by this Deployment has this specification
      containers:
      - image: mohib13/graphene_with_coref:first # Application to run in Deployment's Pods
        name: hostname # Container name
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60 # Number of seconds to wait for connections to terminate before shutting down Pods
```

The service yaml is like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neg-demo-svc # Name of Service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}' # Creates an NEG after an Ingress is created
spec: # Service's specification
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    run: neg-demo-app # Selects Pods labelled run: neg-demo-app
  ports:
  - port: 8080 # Service's port
    targetPort: 8080
```

while ingress is below

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: neg-demo-ing
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: neg-demo-svc # Name of the Service targeted by the Ingress
    servicePort: 8080 # Should match the port used by the Service
```

Update : Describe pod looks like below

```
Name:               neg-demo-app-564654b4d4-gcmz2
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               gke-neg-demo-cluster-default-pool-a0128d7b-z63j/10.0.0.4
Start Time:         Wed, 07 Aug 2019 16:21:20 +0100
Labels:             pod-template-hash=564654b4d4
                    run=neg-demo-app
Annotations:        kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container hostname
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.52.2.5
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/neg-demo-app-564654b4d4
Containers:
  hostname:
    Container ID:   docker://71b1fcada1775844710dca0aa4252a3232e3595f3605de1ae54ab70ec40d823b
    Image:          mohib13/graphene_with_coref:first
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mohib13/graphene_with_coref@sha256:39ff7b18a88020c4e090e37080560df58f382d8bf320f9051559824a7d0e80ad
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 07 Aug 2019 16:21:21 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
    Liveness:     tcp-socket :8080 delay=15s timeout=1s period=20s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    tcp-socket :8080 delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-kghdh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-kghdh:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-kghdh
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From                                                      Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----                                                      -------
  Normal  Scheduled  7m28s  default-scheduler                                         Successfully assigned default/neg-demo-app-564654b4d4-gcmz2 to gke-neg-demo-cluster-default-pool-a0128d7b-z63j
  Normal  Pulled     7m27s  kubelet, gke-neg-demo-cluster-default-pool-a0128d7b-z63j  Container image "mohib13/graphene_with_coref:first" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    7m27s  kubelet, gke-neg-demo-cluster-default-pool-a0128d7b-z63j  Created container
  Normal  Started    7m27s  kubelet, gke-neg-demo-cluster-default-pool-a0128d7b-z63j  Started container
```

Comment: check the reaon using describe pod or check the logs

Comment: Added in description- can you spot anything wrong?

Comment: is your application expose port 8080 ?

Comment: is your application expose port 8080 ?

Comment: Yes, I have now specified that in deployment yaml as well - you can see updated yaml now - but same result

Comment: in your docker file you have expose 8080 ?

Comment: yes, it is exposed. My deployments worked fine without ingress with an external GCP load balancer.

Comment: There is no Warning and Unhealthy status in the pod description. The pod's container has status Ready and only Normal events are there. Where is an error?

Comment: The health appears as UNHEALTHY why i issue `gcloud compute backend-services get-health [BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME] --global ` cmd from the given link. Sorry, but I forgot to share its output in the description and i dont have this machine setup on GKE right now.